# Gitlab external job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I need to integrate security scans of my project files (SAST) in my Gitlab CI/CD pipeline, and it's easy to do with just another job in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, like:

```
security-scan:
  stage: test
  image: my_image:latest
  script:
    - scan run project/folder
```

But the problem is that developers can easily comment this part of the code and prevent the job run.
How can I create some kind of external job which will always be running by the trigger and developers would not be able to modify it?

I found [this discussion](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-create-custom-external-pipeline-with-gitlab-api/55367) on the Gitlab forum, but I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep your .gitlab-ci.yml safe is to ensure only the correct users have the related permissions. This can be done with the CODEOWNERS functionality where you'd avoid changes to your .gitlab-ci.yml without CODEOWNER approvals. E.g. this way :

```
## .gitlab/CODEOWNERS

^[Default]
* @developers-group
 
[Release][2] @maintainers-group
.gitlab/*
.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing external status checks could be another way to handle this problem. This feature is officially only available in Gitlab Ultimate but tools like Renovate Bot use it in CE versions too for their stabilitiy-days implementation, so using it through the API could work.

You'd have to create a webhook check creates a external status-check for each new branch and run the status check for every commit on every branch.

See also: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/status_checks.html